# I cannot start monero-wallet-rpc. I receive the error: no connection to daemon

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

[image]

I can't start monero-wallet-rpc. I received an error: ERROR wallet. RPC Src / Wallet / wallet_rpc_server. cpp: 3443 wallet initialization failed: no connection to daemon. Thanks.

Comment: Obvious question, but is a daemon running?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the daemon is running, and I started it with. / monerod -- stage net -- rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 -- rpc-bind-port 18081 -- rpc-login username: password -- confirm-external-bind -- detach，Is there any good solution? 
Thanks very much！

Comment: Are you starting `monero-wallet-rpc` with the `--stagenet` flag as well?

Comment: Yes, do you need to configure the bitmonero. conf file? Or did I start the daemon in the wrong way? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: can you post the full command you run to start `monero-wallet-rpc`?

Comment: ./monerod --stagenet --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-port 18081 --rpc-login username:password --confirm-external-bind --detach， Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: ./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18089 --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --prompt-for-password --wallet-file dboss2018 --rpc-login xxxxx:xxxxx --confirm-external-bind

Comment: Why are you using different ports for `--rpc-bind-port`? Also, I don't see the `--stagenet` flag for `monero-wallet-rpc`.

Comment: If I use the same port, it has an error: contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:856 Error starting server: bind:Address already in use, ERROR wallet.rpc src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:3449 Failed to initialize wallet RPC server

Comment: I ran it again, this time it returned a new error: Wallet initialization failed: Mainnet wallet cannot be opened as stage net Wallet。

Comment: Could you create a new stagenet wallet with `monero-wallet-rpc`?

Comment: The problem is that the daemon must be specified to start at 127.0.0.1. Otherwise, an error may occur when you start the Wallet RPC: Wallet initialization failed: no connection to daemon. Thank you very much!

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Did you perhaps manage to get it running? If not, can you have a look at jtgrassie's answer?

Comment: very nice ， First of all thank you all for your suggestion, this is very useful, I have successfully start and run it, now it's all normal.

Comment: All right, good to hear! You can thank jtgrassie :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have to be running `monerod` for `monero-wallet-rpc` to work.

Next, if you start `monerod` with `--stagenet`, you have to start the wallet with `--stagenet` also. If you create a wallet for mainnet, it won't open on stagenet, same as for testnet. You cannot mix networks / daemons / wallets.

Next, you only need specify a rpc-bind-ip if you will be connecting *remotely* to the wallet RPC or daemon RPC. By default they listen on localhost so if you want to allow remote connections, you must specify an IP address they will bind to.

So, with all this understood, a setup with locally accessible only daemon and remotely accessible wallet RPC running from the same host, and both with their RPC's requiring login, you could start like:

```
monerod --rpc-login daemon-user:daemon-pass --detach

monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 18089 --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --confirm-external-bind \
  --rpc-login rpc-user:rpc-pass --daemon-login daemon-user:daemon-pass \
  --prompt-for-password --wallet-file my-wallet
```

If you add `--stagenet` to one, add it to the other too.

Here's a variation which will allow both of these RPC servers to be externally accessible and using non-standard ports for demonstration:

```
monerod --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --rpc-bind-port 18088 --confirm-external-bind \
  --rpc-login daemon-user:daemon-pass --detach

monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --rpc-bind-port 18089 --confirm-external-bind \
  --rpc-login rpc-user:rpc-pass --daemon-login daemon-user:daemon-pass \
  --daemon-port 18088 --prompt-for-password --wallet-file my-wallet
```

Lastly, all these flags are documented:

```
monerod --help
monero-wallet-rpc --help
```

Comment: I'm glad! I have been solved, thank you for your advice, wish you have a nice evening!